# difficulty loading packages in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have spent hours trying to think of a ways to install some packages in R that just refuse to load. I have tried uninstalling and installing again, downloading from URL etc etc. but nothing seems to work. Please help me before I give up on teach entirely

{

```
library(psych)
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘psych’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/alan/Library/R/3.5/library/lattice/libs/lattice.so':
  dlopen(/Users/alan/Library/R/3.5/library/lattice/libs/lattice.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/alan/Library/R/3.5/library/lattice/libs/lattice.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: lattice.so requires version 3.5.0 or later, but libR.dylib provides version 3.1.0

Comment: `library()` is different than `install.packages()`. Try `install.packages("psych")`.

Comment: I did that. The package downloads and seems to install OK but then this is what happens when I try and call the library

Comment: {    install.packages("psych")
Installing package into ‘/Users/alan/Library/R/3.5/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/psych_1.8.10.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5813168 bytes (5.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/58/h02bqqbn3q3bnmd69djkzhzm0000gn/T//Rtmpz33LSd/downloaded_packages    }

Comment: I've even tried downloading the libraries as .tar .gz and the same issue keeps happening

Comment: Try this: `install.packages("psych", type = "binary")` found from this link [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-installing-packages-on-r-3-5-1-running-on-mac-os-x-10-13-sierra/14758/5)

Comment: the problem is not with the package, but with a mismatch in the underlying R version.  It looks like you might have some leftover junk from an earlier R installation?  I would try to locate the `libR.dylib` file on your system and see how old it is ...  short of that, completely uninstalling/reinstalling R itself would probably be wise.

Comment: It's possible that your are using an older version of R. The error message says "... _so requires version 3.5.0 or later_ ..."  What version of R are you using?

Comment: Yes! I had a previous version of R installed so found the directory a directory full of libraries that must have been clashing. I just deleted the whole folder and went from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a previous version of R installed so found the directory a directory full of libraries that must have been clashing. I just deleted the whole folder and went from scratch